# Creating a customized list of custom views

Tags: android, android-layout, components, custom-view

I want to create a list like seen in the picture below and was wondering which one of androids controls would be the best option to do so?

For every row in the list I could use a custom view that has `max-Val` and `current-Val`, then draw a rectangle based on that.

But for the list, the headings, and the today indicator: What control should I use here?

[image: budget list sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RecyclerView` is probably the way to go.

Define different view types for

- the actual header,
- the section headers, and
- the list items

Setting it up like that will get you the whole screen *except* the 'Today' marker.

To add that marker you need to draw on top of the views in the recyclerview. There are 2 options

- Just add another view on top of the recyclerview where you draw the text and line, which is possible but not really the cleanest approach, or
- use a `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` with which you draw the 'Today' text on top of the first item after the header, and decorate (draw over) every subsequent view beneath with the vertical line.